# How to get code completion in brackets for CasperJS modules and test functions?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, code-completion, adobe-brackets

CasperJS has files with modules and files with test functions.

I want to use brackets IDE to write tests but I do not have code completion (like intellisense) commands when I press ctrl+space.

How can I import those files on brackets IDE to can be my library of CasperJS functions?